# how do i remove duplicates from each column and still keep all the data in mysql ? its it possible ? pls help

Tags: mysql, mariadb, xampp

```
SELECT 
   star_mss2_VideoMaster.Video_Title,
   star_vlss_vid-location.video_location,
   star_alss_aud-location.audio_location,
   star_vss_VideoFile.Video-filename,
   star_Afss_AudioFile.audio-filename,
   star_stss_SvToLoctn.S_Location,
   star_wses_ws_filename.wondershare_fileName,
   star_wses_ws_filename.vid_length
FROM
   star_mss2_VideoMaster` 
JOIN 
   star_vlss_vid-location ON star_vlss_vid-location.video_title_id=star_mss2_VideoMaster.Video_id
JOIN
   star_alss_aud-location ON star_alss_aud-location.video_title_id=star_vlss_vid-location.video_title_id
JOIN 
   star_vss_VideoFile ON star_mss2_VideoMaster.Video_id=star_vss_VideoFile.video_title_id
JOIN 
   star_Afss_AudioFile ON star_Afss_AudioFile.video_title_id=star_mss2_VideoMaster.Video_id
JOIN 
   star_stss_SvToLoctn ON star_mss2_VideoMaster.Video_id=star_stss_SvToLoctn.video_title_id
JOIN 
   star_wses_ws_filename ON star_wses_ws_filename.saveto_id=star_stss_SvToLoctn.st_id
```

[image]

A simpler version:

```
Table 1
+------+----=----+
| v_id | a_Title |
+------+-----==--+
| 1    | abc     |
| 2    | abcs    |
-----------------+

Table 2
+-----+-------+-------+
| sid | Title | v_id  |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 1   | abc   | 2     |
| 2   | abcs  | 2     |
--------------+-------+

table 3 : Select * from table 1 
          JOIN Table 2 using (v_id);
+------+------------++-----+-------+---------+
| v_id | a_Title || sid | Title |   v_id  |
+------+-----------++-----+-------+---------+
| 2    | abcs     || 1   | abc   | 2      |
---------------------+-----------------------
| 2    | abcs    || 2   | abcs  | 2       |
--------------------+--------------+---------+
```

I don't like this output. There are two *abcs* under *a_Title*.

I want output like:

```
+------+---------++-----+-------+
| v_id | a_Title || sid | Title |
+------+---------++-----+-------+
| 2    | abcs    || 1   | abc   |
-----------------+---------------
|      |         || 2   | abcs  |
-----------------+--------------+
```

[image]

Comment: what is the picture supposed to represent? ... how does the SQL statement relate to the picture?

Comment: Please create a simpler example. Show the actual result of your command, and the desired result. Avoid pictures of text, as they are hard to read by some people, and impossible to read by others as well as search engines.

Comment: The picture represents my current output. If you observe column 1 (video_title) it has 6 entries but each entry is the same. They are repeating because some column in some other table has multiple entry under the same id..Similarly with other column 2,3,4,56,7,8 they are repeating the same data again and again. I don't want that. I want something that can remove this dubplicates entries from each column and also keep everything as it is.

Comment: Let me simplify,
I have Table 1 with video_id..Now I create table 2 containing video_id as one of its field. Under table 2 I have two rows with same video_id. Now when I join both table 1 and table 2 using video_id I get table 3 with two rows and two columns. Table 3 containing table1 column name has duplicates entries. I don't want to see table1 column with same entry under table 3. I only want to see unique values in each column but I want all the rows from both the table.

Comment: did you actually test your sample simplyfied join ? you should get **one** line only (where `vid=2`). line with `sid=1` shouldn't be on the join result.

Comment: Yeah I remove that column vid=2 just for simplicity...

Comment: I join the table using v_id and not sid @archemar.. so sid=1 and sid=2 both values will be visible.

Comment: It's a lot of effort, for very little gain... What you see is a natural product of how databases perform joins and create resulting data. Removing it is a presentational thing, i.e. not the database's job. If you remove it from the data source, then everything will go crazy if you sort the data by some column. Better that you leave the data alone and program your UI to hide the cells if the ones output on the previous row had the same values. (And if you don't have a UI, then just put up with it as-is, or write a UI, or burn a lot of time going to considerable lengths to remove it)

Comment: This is what I did.. I selected a distinct column and use the join SQL to print each column separately.. So I repeated the SQL for each column and I now I have my desired result. Anyways thank you all..